# Implemetation of Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new to Xamarin and I am trying to implement Navigation drawer to an existing activity.

The existing activity has an actionbar on top and Frgament container containing bottom navigation buttons. The fragment is getting filled in Oncreate method of the activity.

Code goes something like this.

TestActivity.cs

```
  protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        SupportActionBar.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.NavigationBar);
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.FragmentContainer);

        Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
        Support.V7.App.ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new Support.V7.App.ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_open, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.AddDrawerListener(toggle);

        toggle.SyncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
        navigationView.SetNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        UpdateFragment(new TestFragment());
    }
```

Frgamentcontainer.axml(Some portions of)

```
  <RelativeLayout      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:id="@+id/containerMain"
   android:minWidth="25px"
   android:minHeight="25px"
   style="@style/ActivityLayout">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottomBar"
    android:id="@+id/container" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/status"
    android:background="#2980b9"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

I want to replace the existing support action bar with NavigationDrawer with toolbar containing hamburger icon.

I have tried like this below

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

```
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

        SupportActionBar.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.NewDrwerLayout);
     }
```

NewDrawerLayout.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout               xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                                       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                                    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
                                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                                    tools:openDrawer="start">
  <include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:menu="@drawable/activities" />

 </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.axml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
```

and in TestActivity.cs I have like below

```
Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

            DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
            Support.V7.App.ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new Support.V7.App.ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_open, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.AddDrawerListener(toggle);

            toggle.SyncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
            navigationView.SetNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

After all the above changes I could see the toolbar with hamburger but navigation drawer panel is cropping and showing the content only in the supportActionBar region. 

Please help me.

TestActivity.cs

 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

            SupportActionBar.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.NavigationBar);
            SupportActionBar.SetDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.FragmentContainer);

            Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar toolbar = FindViewById<Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);

            DrawerLayout drawer = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
            Support.V7.App.ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new Support.V7.App.ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_open, Resource.String.navigation_drawer_close);
            drawer.AddDrawerListener(toggle);

            toggle.SyncState();

            NavigationView navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
            navigationView.SetNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

            UpdateFragment(new TestFragment());
        }


Frgamentcontainer.axml(Some portions of)

   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/containerMain"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    style="@style/ActivityLayout">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:id="@+id/bottomBar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="65dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="2dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/swhlogo5"
                android:id="@+id/logo"
                style="@style/LogoIcon"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/textRdName"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize = "end" 
                style="@style/SmallText"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            <ImageView
                android:background="@drawable/info"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/imgInfo"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottomBar"
        android:id="@+id/container" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:background="#2980b9"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

After all the above changes I could see the toolbar with hamburger but navigation drawer panel is cropping and showing the content only in the supportActionBar region.

Please help me.

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo so that we can test with it?